# Array reduce with associative array

Tags: php, array-reduce

I have an array like this

```
 $filter_array = Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [fv_id] => 1
                [fv_value] => Red
                [filter_id] => 1
                [filter_name] => Color
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [fv_id] => 2
                [fv_value] => Blue
                [filter_id] => 1
                [filter_name] => Color
            )

    )
```

I would like to reduce the array by having **filter_name** and **filter_id** on top of array which is similar for all arrays.

```
$newArray = array_reduce($filter_array,function($carry,$item){

            $allFilterValues[] = array(
                'fv_id' => $item['fv_id'],
                'fv_value' => $item['fv_value'],
            );

             $formated_array = array(
                'filter_id' => $item['filter_id'],
                'filter_name' => $item['filter_name'],
                'filter_values' => $allFilterValues
            );
            return $formated_array;
        });
```

But I am just getting the last array iterations value on **filter_values**

```
Array
(
    [filter_id] => 1
    [filter_name] => Color
    [filter_values] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [fv_id] => 2
                    [fv_value] => Blue
                )

        )

)
```

But I want the array be like this.

```
Array
(
    [filter_id] => 1
    [filter_name] => Color
    [filter_values] => Array
        (
                [0] => Array
                (
                    [fv_id] => 1
                    [fv_value] => Red
                ),

                [1] => Array
                (
                    [fv_id] => 2
                    [fv_value] => Blue
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: If you are merging on `filter_id` why do you abandon it as an array key?  Are you sure you have the key names as they should be?  It seems to me you should be using `filter_id` and `filter_name` as keys before each subgroup.

Comment: On each iteration of `array_reduce` callback you should return `$carry`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On each iteration of `array_reduce` callback function **must** return current `$carry` value:

```
$newArray = array_reduce($filter_array,function($carry,$item){
    // create key so as to distinct values from each other
    $key = $item['filter_id'] . '-' . $item['filter_name'];

    // check if created key exists in `$carry`, 
    // if not - we init it with some data
    if (empty($carry[$key])) {
        $carry[$key] = [
            'filter_id' => $item['filter_id'],
            'filter_name' => $item['filter_name'],
            'filter_values' => []
        ];
    }

    // add values to `filter_values`
    $carry[$key]['filter_values'][] = [
        'fv_id' => $item['fv_id'],
        'fv_value' => $item['fv_value'],
    ];

    return $carry;
}, []);

// if you want to reindex `$newArray` from 0:
$newArray = array_values($newArray);
```

**Update**: if and only if in your `$filter_array` values of `'filter_id'` and `'filter_name'` are **always** the same you can simplify your code:

```
$newArray = [];
$first = true;
foreach ($filter_array as $item) {
    if ($first) {
        $first = false;
        $newArray = [
            'filter_id' => $item['filter_id'],
            'filter_value' => $item['filter_name'],
            'filter_values' => []
        ];
    }

    $newArray['filter_values'][] = [
        'fv_id' => $item['fv_id'],
        'fv_value' => $item['fv_value'],
    ];
}
echo'<pre>',print_r($newArray),'</pre>';
```

Comment: Is any other array function makes things easier than this?

Comment: I suppose no. But you can rewrite this as a `foreach`.

Comment: Can you please tell me why you have passed [] after the callback argument in array_reduce?

Comment: Created a little update for code simplifying. As for your question - I pass `[]` as initial value of `$carry`. Of course, php can decide what initial value of `$carry` you use, so it's just my personal approach.